# Trying to select a value from a JSON file to output to HTML

Tags: javascript, json

So I have 6 divs and I want to output just the jackpot value to each of the div using the JSON code that I provided. My problem is that I can't seem to select the jackpot value as I get the following error. 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jackpots' of undefined
        at renderHTML (js.js:24)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (js.js:10)

JSON

```
  {
  "jackpots": [
    {
      "jackpot": "417,961.29", 
      "game": "ElmStreet"
    }, 
    {
      "jackpot": "3,741,373.46", 
      "game": "MillionairGenie"
    }, 
    {
      "jackpot": "3,741,373.46", 
      "game": "TreasureFair"
    }, 
    {
      "jackpot": "70,004.09", 
      "game": "JacksPot"
    }, 
    {
      "jackpot": "14,749.68", 
      "game": "IrishRiches"
    }, 
    {
      "jackpot": "17,932.43", 
      "game": "CasinoReels"
    }
  ]
}
```

JS

```
    var pageCounter = 1;
var animalContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("jackpot");
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
for (var i = 0 ; i < icon.length; i++) {
icon[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bZlZOVDMKq?indent=2');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      renderHTML(ourData);
      pageCounter++;
  };
  ourRequest.send();
})};

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";

for (var i = 0 ; i < animalContainer.length; i++) {
  animalContainer[i].innerHTML = "<p>" + data[i].jackpots.jackpot + "</p>"
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="games-container">

    <div class="game Jackpot">
    <img class="icon" class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >Jackpot</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="game TreasureFair">
    <img class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >TreasureFair</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="game Millionaire Genie">
    <img class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >Millionaire Genie</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="game Irish Riches">
    <img class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >Irish Riches</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="game ElmStreet">
    <img class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >ElmStreet</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

    <div class="game CasinoReels">
    <img class="icon" src="jackpot.png" alt="">
    <label class="name" >CasinoReels</label>
    <label class="jackpot" >$0</label>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple, multiple times.  Please do / show some research effort.

Comment: Additionally, try to use ES6, avoid declaring variables using `var`, and also avoid using for-loops and use `.map` instead, as it is less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, where you reference data, `data[i].jackpots.jackpot`, the array that you are trying to reference is "jackpots" not "data", so maybe try `data.jackpots[i].jackpot`.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what the `data` object looks like, but `data.jackpots` is undefined, so I recommend using `console.log()` to find out what the object looks like so you can figure out how to reference it.